# Creating custom class with restrictions for number & letter value

Tags: java, boolean

I want to create a custom class for an "employee ID number," but it needs to output in the format ###-X, where each of the three numbers can only be in the 0-9 range, and the X letter can only be from the letters A-M.

For setting the employee number I have it setup so that:

```
public void setEmployeeNumber(String num)
{
  if (validEmployeeNum(num))
  {
     employeeNumber = num;
  }
  else
  {
     employeeNumber = "";
  }
}
```

and then was planning on creating a boolean "validEmployeeNum" with the constraints listed above, but I'm a bit confused about how to accomplish this. Can anyone assist with how I can create a boolean so that ###-X can only be in 0-9 range for each number, and the letter can only be from the letters A-M?

Example valid input: 195-C

Example invalid input: 99522-V

Comment: How would you check if the characters match?

Comment: You can use regular expression for this

Comment: If the input is not valid I would throw an IllegalArgumentException, I wouldn't set a boolean which may or may not be looked at.

Comment: Definitely a job for regular expression.

Comment: and the regular expression is `[0-9]{3}-[A-M]`

Comment: Or, `^(\d{3})-([A-M])$`; you get grouping to separate the digits from the character code, too.

Answer (score 0):

Classic application use case for [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html). Here's a taste:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Match {

    static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{3})-([A-M])$");

    static boolean isValid(String num) {
        return pattern.matcher(num).matches();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String test : new String[] {
            "195-C",
            "1195-C",
            "195-Z"
        }) {
            System.out.println(test + " valid? " + isValid(test));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
195-C valid? true
1195-C valid? false
195-Z valid? false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use `Regex` to see if the string `matches` the regex you supply.

```
^([0-9]{3})-([A-M])
```

Will match what you are looking for. A demo is shown [here](http://regexr.com/3929v)

Comment: You can also add a caret to not match the extra digits like "11195-C": http://regexr.com/392a2

Comment: That site doesn't seem to want to accept a dollar sign? I tried to make it also not accept extra junk at the end.

Comment: I believe they made the `/g` imply it in their code base. It is not accepting extra stuff for me.

Comment: Oh, it tries to match the regex against the whole content of your sample text, as one input. So adding $ only works in this case: http://regexr.com/392bo

Comment: Good find, I was unaware of that feature in Regexr.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public Boolean validEmployeeNum(string num) { 
    if(num.length() != 5)
        return false;

    if('num.charAt(0)' >= 48 && 'num.charAt(0)' <= 57) {
        if('num.charAt(1)' >= 48 && 'num.charAt(1)' <= 57) {
            if('num.charAt(2)' >= 48 && 'num.charAt(2)' <= 57) {
                if('num.charAt(4)' >= 65 && 'num.charAt(4)' <= 77) {
                    return true;
               }
           }
       }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Of course this is assuming that every employee number is a string that is 5 characters long.

Comment: I would use character literals like `'9'` or `'A'` rather than using magic numbers. But then again, regex is much more efficient at this job than character-to-character comparisons.

Comment: regex is much more efficient, but for people who may have had little experience with it before may find this to be more simpler to wrap their head around.

Answer (score 0):

Either use regular expressions, as the commenters suggest (a really good suggestion, by the way) or do something like this:

```
public static boolean validateNumber(String empNum)  
{  
   if(empNum.length() == 5)  
   {  
      char char1 = empNum.charAt(0);  
      char char2 = empNum.charAt(1);  
      char char3 = empNum.charAt(2);  
      char char4 = empNum.charAt(3);  
      char char5 = empNum.charAt(4);  

      if(char1 >= '0' && char1 <= '9')
      {
         if(char2 >= '0' && char2 <= '9')
         {
            if(char3 >= '0' && char3 <= '9')
            {
               if(char4 == '-')
               {
                  if(char5 >= 'A' && char5 <= 'M')
                  {
                     return true;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This, my friend, is definitely not preferable to regular expressions, but it certainly works.